# Why Javascript changing the value of an attribute? Not passing it to another variable

Tags: javascript

So, I have:

```
const Transaction = {
   all: [{
      description: 'Luz',
      amount: -50000,
      date: '23/01/2021',
   }, {
      description: 'Website',
      amount: 056,
      date: '23/01/2021',
   }, {
      description: 'Internet',
      amount: -25000,
      date: '23/01/2021',
   }, {
      description: 'App mobile',
      amount: 900000,
      date: '23/01/2021',
   }]
}
```

Then I print it on console without doing anything before it:

```
const App = {
   init() {
      Transaction.all.forEach((transaction) => {
         console.log(transaction)
      })
   }
```

The output is:

```
{description: "Luz", amount: -50000, date: "23/01/2021"}
{description: "Website", amount: 46, date: "23/01/2021"}
{description: "Internet", amount: -25000, date: "23/01/2021"}
{description: "App mobile", amount: 900000, date: "23/01/2021"}
```

Why Website amount(declared as 056) became 46??

Comment: `056` is *octal* which converts to `46` decimal.

Comment: thanks VLAZ I had no idea of that and solved the issue declaring amount: Number('056')

Answer (score 0):

Because of the leading zero, the value is interpreted as an octal and then the value is converted to decimal.

Simply remove the leading zero to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Actually I need the initial zero because of some other treatment. I have solved it by defining like that: amount: Number('056'). I had no idea it could be related to octal. :D thanks!